# What are Mac alternatives to Storage Spaces in Windows 8/Windows Server 2012?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, storage, windows

I like the Storage Spaces feature in Windows 8/Windows Server 2012, but since I'm mostly working on Mac computers I would like to know if there are any Mac alternatives or equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is not really. The more in-depth answer is that there's nothing directly comparable, but there are some alternatives worth looking at, depending on your needs.

### RAID

The most basic option is using software RAID (either through [built-in OS X tools](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5834) or [third party software](http://www.softraid.com/)) to create a mirrored (RAID 1) or striped (RAID 0) volume out of multiple disks. This is pretty limited in its flexibility, and to my knowledge there's no software that supports RAID 5/6 on OS X.

If you have a Mac Pro, you could get a [hardware RAID card](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB845Z/A/mac-pro-raid-card), which offers more options in terms of RAID levels, but is still somewhat limited for expansion, as well as costly.

### External Units

The [Drobo](http://drobo.com) is somewhat popular for direct-attached storage. It provides   more flexibility in terms of mixing and matching capacities, but it has not always had the greatest reputation for performance.

### NAS

Using a NAS, whether a pre-packaged solution or a custom built one running some variety of Windows or *nix gives you greater flexibility in most cases, and over wired ethernet can be faster than a Drobo. It can get more complex, and you run into the limitations of networked drives — in particular, Time Machine isn't really built to deal with network drives (it can be done, but gets a bit jacky), but it can also give you the greatest control over your configuration and future expandability.